# reading file from Lua in cocos2d-x

Tags: iphone, lua, cocos2d-x

I am working on a cocos2d-x project in Lua. I have a problem with syntax openien file, when I invoke:

```
cocos2d.CCFileData:new("file.txt", "w"+)
```

I always get error:

> Cocos2d: ...80-C048-4F64-BC52-4849C0AD02F5/Main.lua:30: attempt to index field 'CCFileData' (a nil value)

What am I doing wrong? i cannot get any doc info. I am doing this on iOS.

Comment: Note: Lua is a proper name, not an acronym. It's not LUA.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `cocos2d.CCFileData` is `nil`. How is `cocos2d.CCFileData` defined?

Comment: In my opinion, it should return CCFileData object:http://www.cocos2d-x.org/embedded/cocos2d-x/db/dbb/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_file_data.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure the call must be prefixed with "cocos2d"? Without knowing cocos2d-x but according to the error message maybe this is the correct call?

```
CCFileData:new("file.txt", "w+")
```

2) The "w"+ is certainly incorrect. It needs to be "w+" all in quotes:

```
cocos2d.CCFileData:new("file.txt", "w+")
```

Comment: Ad 1 this issue is not working due to CCFileData is not implemented yet in cocos2d-x I use today.
Ad 2. You're right. It was my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Well the CCFileData is just not implemented yet in Cocos2d-x. I have managed this by using io.open lua funcion. It helped to have Lua file routines.

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of call:

```
    xmlFilePath = CCFileUtils::fullPathFromRelativePath("NameOfFile.xml");
```

I just spent a decent 30 minutes looking for a working version of this. The Cocos2d author, in January, recommends using a different file which I have yet to get working, but I just tested this and I am successfully reading an XML file finally. Thought I'd share this method, since iOS usually uses

```
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"" ofType:@""];
```

styles to get the paths. We have to do similar, and that's the cocos2d-x method of doing it.